# using bind_param with mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysqli

I want bind input from user befor add data to database , I wrote this code but I don't know how I complete it

```
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'user');
$con->set_charset("utf8");
$result = mysqli_query($con,("INSERT INTO users(name, email, user_phone_number, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
```

user input `$name , $email , $user_phone_number , $password`  this pramter I don't want add directly to my database for that I used ????

in `PDO` I use `bindValue` but here what I should do ?

Comment: Do spend the time to go through the manual first http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php - There also isn't enough code in your question to support it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I update my question

Comment: again; read the manual. There are examples in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use `mysqli_query()` with prepared statements, you use `mysqli_prepare()`.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users(name, email, user_phone_number, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $name, $email, $user_phone_number, $password);
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```